# PHP Return Key Given Different Key in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a unique problem.

I have a few arrays that each have 2 items and are in the following form:

```
$arr=Array
(
    [TEAM1] => 113.03
    [TEAM2] => 103.52
)
```

I am trying to create a function that given the array (`$arr`) and one of the keys (`TEAM1`), it would return the other key (`TEAM2`). The array will always only have 2 values and the key you put in will always exist.

My problem is that I have no idea how to start this.. if the key was `0` or `1` it would be easy selecting the other row but for this I am not sure how to start

Comment: `$str = 'TEAM2'; $notTeam2 = array_diff_key($arr, [$str => null]);` [Demo](https://3v4l.org/EeO2T)

Comment: `$result = preg_grep("/$key/", array_keys($arr), PREG_GREP_INVERT);`

Comment: @MarkBaker: Your solution worked. If you post it as answer, ill approve it. Also how do I just return the value (i.e. 113.03) and not the whole array

Comment: `unset $arr[$key];` `reset($arr);` `$value = current($arr);` should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the key that isn't `$str`:

```
$str = 'TEAM2';
$notTeam2 = array_diff_key($arr, [$str => null]);
```

Using array_dereferencing to get the value without needing to know the key:

```
$notTeam2Value = array_values($notTeam2)[0];
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZKrTI)